# Problems while executing slimerjs on linux (Centos 6.5 32bit)

Tags: centos, xvfb

I'm not used to work with Linux yet I wanted to try to use slimerjs on a Linux vps in order to have access to php exec function since most hosting companies disable that function.

I did manage to install xampp, vsftpd, xulrunner, xvfb and slimerjs (standalone version).

When I run the following command, slimerjs is launched, yet only console.log functions are called:

```
xvfb-run ./slimerjs hello.js
```

I tried adding sudo at the beginning yet the result is the same.

Here is the "response" of the above command:

```
Hi
6 XSELINUXs still allocated at reset
SCREEN: 0 objects of 132 bytes = 0 total bytes 0 private allocs
DEVICE: 0 objects of 64 bytes = 0 total bytes 0 private allocs
CLIENT: 0 objects of 112 bytes = 0 total bytes 0 private allocs
WINDOW: 0 objects of 20 bytes = 0 total bytes 0 private allocs
PIXMAP: 2 objects of 8 bytes = 16 total bytes 0 private allocs
GC: 4 objects of 8 bytes = 32 total bytes 0 private allocs
CURSOR: 0 objects of 4 bytes = 0 total bytes 0 private allocs
DBE_WINDOW: 0 objects of 12 bytes = 0 total bytes 0 private allocs
TOTAL: 6 objects, 48 bytes, 0 allocs
2 PIXMAPs still allocated at reset
PIXMAP: 2 objects of 8 bytes = 16 total bytes 0 private allocs
GC: 4 objects of 8 bytes = 32 total bytes 0 private allocs
CURSOR: 0 objects of 4 bytes = 0 total bytes 0 private allocs
DBE_WINDOW: 0 objects of 12 bytes = 0 total bytes 0 private allocs
TOTAL: 6 objects, 48 bytes, 0 allocs
4 GCs still allocated at reset
GC: 4 objects of 8 bytes = 32 total bytes 0 private allocs
CURSOR: 0 objects of 4 bytes = 0 total bytes 0 private allocs
DBE_WINDOW: 0 objects of 12 bytes = 0 total bytes 0 private allocs
TOTAL: 4 objects, 32 bytes, 0 allocs
./slimerjs: line 172:  4568 Aborted                 "$SLIMERJSLAUNCHER" -app $SLIMERDIR/application.ini $PROFILE -no-remote "$@" 2> /dev/null
/usr/bin/xvfb-run: line 171: kill: (4558) - No such process
```

Here is the content of hello.js

```
console.log("Hi");
var page = require("webpage").create();
console.log("Hi");
page.open("http://www.youtube.com/")
.then(function(status){
    console.log("Hi");
     if (status == "success") {
         console.log("The title of the page is: "+ page.title);
     }
     else {
         console.log("Sorry, the page is not loaded");
     }
     page.close();
     setTimeout(function(){phantom.exit();},5000);
});
```

Only the first console.log is executed. If I add 10 consecutive console.log's at the beginning, all of them are executed. The next code doesn’t execute the `setTimeout` function:

```
console.log("Hi");
setTimeout(function(){console.log("Hi");});
```

To summarize: if, while executing the code, something else but console.log is found, it will stop there.

Before trying slimerjs I tried phantomjs and it works perfectly! I don't know what is the problem with slimerjs. Maybe because I'm trying to execute it with xvfb?

Answer (score 1):

I too was getting:

`./slimerjs: line 172:  4568 Aborted "$SLIMERJSLAUNCHER" -app $SLIMERDIR/application.ini $PROFILE -no-remote "$@" 2> /dev/null`

until I remembered to run `export SLIMERJSLAUNCHER=/usr/bin/firefox`.

Note, you need to have Firefox installed.